# Using the Raspberry Pi Cam at 110 degrees Celsius

Tags: camera, webcam, temperature, raspicam

A CCD camera is required to be placed in a hot environment of up to 120 deg Celsius. I am thinking of using the [Raspberry Pi Camera Module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E1GGE40) which I already have. However I am unable to find any specs for its operating temperature onlin.

Does the Raspberry Pi Camera module work under those high temperatures or are there any other heat resistat cameras compatible with the Raspberry Pi cam, hopefully a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Melting point of typical solder.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder)

> .. with a typical melting range of 90 to 450 °C

You are correct, there is no proper specification about this camera and the only source might have been the ROHS certificate. In 2006 EU prohibided the use of solder in all general use appliances, except capacitors. *[As of point two in the wheras directives.](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2012:348:0016:0017:EN:PDF)  So to be ROHS certified they must have used Lead Free Solder

> popular lead-free solder alloy family is based on the reduced melting
>   point of the Sn-Ag-Cu ternary eutectic behavior (217 ˚C)

You still have the problem of the plastics which may start to melt over 100deg Celsius, deform or whatever else. The PCB can withstand up to 180deg Celsius for short periods but long exposrue may cause it to warp or start to smoulder. And it smells really bad!

[image]

**Unless otherwise specified, you should not expect it to work too long under higher temperatures than 80deg Celsius.** Like @Steve Robillard linked to the question, the IC and other electrical equipment might start to fail at about 100degrees Celsius too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the absolute specs of the camera module (though given the price I would not expect it to be far different than the Pi's -40 to 85 degrees C). The camera's comes with a very short cable and 110 degrees Celsius is outside the operating range of the Pi itself. So even if the camera was built with components that could survive at those temperatures the Pi itself could not. See this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/103/56) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

At $32,- I'd just try, and see if it works. Camera's that are designed for those kinds of conditions will probably cost into the hundreds if not thousands of dollars.

You could try putting the board into an enclosure, and force cool outside air though it with some tubing and a fan of sorts.

Also be aware of air-humidity.