# How does a Raspberry Pi deal with high temperature?

Tags: temperature, cpu, cooling

Is there a overheating protection circuit integrated into the Raspberry Pi like in desktop processors from Intel or AMD? When I did research about this question I just found vendor specification about operating temperatures ranges. How does a Raspberry Pi deal with high temperature?

I've tried it out. I measured the external temperature and monitored also the temperature provided by the sensor in the AP. I run a benchmark with the same result on room temperature and when I heated the PI up with hot air to 70°.

[image]

Comment: see also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103/whats-the-maximum-minimum-running-temperature? and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79510/is-high-temperature-handled-by-hardware-or-software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as the temperature rises the CPU frequency is lowered to prevent damage. The throttling begins around 82 degree Celsius. You can check the CPU Frequency with the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

or using the GUI widget.

The following links provide additional info and benchmarks:

http://www.sbeddoes.com/blog/2016/3/7/yia8uhjlb9hoau76a38jc21z3blp1e
http://makezine.com/2016/03/02/raspberry-pi-3-not-halt-catch-fire/

Comment: Where can I find this information? What is the stepping?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Very interesting.  That might explain why the RDP terminal became so slow before it totally stopped when mine overheated in that black plastic "official" case.  It had no vents, and when I took off the top and touched the heat sink it burned my finger.