# Pi3 Model B reaching 100+ degree Celsius immediately after boot

Tags: gpio, pi-3, sensor

Have a Pi3 Model B, was playing around with GPIO and trying to integrate a PIRO sensor (IR). Must have done something wrong with the circuit as now the Pi immediately reaches 100+ degree Celsius within few seconds after booting with a thermometer icon on top left of the screen. How to fix it?

Comment: Remove the circuit from the GPIO. You seriously risk damaging your Pi permanently with those kind of temperatures. I suggest posting a picture of the circuit and how it is connected to the GPIO. This will allow us to find where the problem is.

Comment: I'm sorry to say a rapidly overheating SoC is a sign the Pi is dead or dying.

Comment: @DarthVader The circuit is no more connected to the GPIO. Still the temperature is spiking above 100 degrees C. Pi boots with the thermometer icon on top right and reboots in some time. Any clue if this Pi can be salvaged?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3B processor and SD card overheat](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85395/raspberry-pi-3b-processor-and-sd-card-overheat)

Answer (score 1):

The Pi 3 should throttle its CPU down when the system temperature reaches [around 80-85 degrees Celsius](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103/whats-the-maximum-minimum-running-temperature). If your Pi doesn't do this then it's broken. As a last ditch effort you might consider trying a [small heatsink](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3082) and/or running a fan over the board, but it fundamentally shouldn't be getting that hot.

I think it's probably time to return or junk the Pi. Trying to fix it is going to be more expensive and time consuming than makes sense in the context of a £35 device.